# Problema en Python con Programación Orientado a Objetos

Tags: python, poo

Hice un programa de reconocimiento de voz para realizar determinadas acciones y lo quise actualizar aplicando la programación orientada a objetos, para que quede mucho mejor el código. Pero ahora no me compila
Yo creo que el problema esta en la función **Interpretar**. El programa recopila lo que se dice por el micrófono, pero al momento de accionar con la función Interpretar salta ese error en la consola.

Si necesitan mas información sobre como funciona el código, háganmelo saber.
Las Librerías no las pongo por que no creo que sea necesario.

```
class Asistente:
    def __init__(self):

        self.engine = voz.init()
        self.voices = self.engine.getProperty('voices')
        #indice para voz [0]  - Ingles-ZIRA - [1] Español - [2] Español
        self.engine.setProperty('voice', self.voices[2].id)
        self.engine.setProperty("rate", 140)
        # Escuchar el audio con el micrófono de mi computadora

    def Interpretar(self):
        self.comando_de_audio = self.comando_de_audio.split(' ')
        self.youtube = ('YouTube') in self.comando_de_audio or ('youtube') in self.comando_de_audio
        self.escribir = ('bloc de notas') in self.comando_de_audio
        self.shutdown = ('apagar equipo') in self.comando_de_audio
        self.telegram = ('Telegram') in self.comando_de_audio or ('telegram') in self.comando_de_audio
        self.spotify = ('Spotify') in self.comando_de_audio
        self.clima = ('Clima') in self.comando_de_audio
        #vereda = ('Playlist Vereda') in comando_de_audio
        #RAM = ('ram' or 'Ram')  in comando_de_audio
        #estatus =  
  
        def apagarequipo(self):    
            self.sub.call('start shutdown /s', shell = True )
        def abrirblocNotas(self):
            self.sub.call('start notepad.exe', shell = True) 
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Block de Notas ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
        def abriryoutube(self):
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Youtube ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
            #sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/Desktop/Assistant Charlotte/Batch/youtube.bat')
        def abrirtelegram(self):
            self.engine.say(' Abriendo Telegram ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/AppData/Roaming/Telegram Desktop/Telegram.exe')
        def abrirSpotify(self):
            self.engine.say('Abriendo Spotify')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.sub.call(r'C:/Users/Jeremias Davison/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe')

        if self.youtube:
            abriryoutube()
        elif self.escribir:
            abrirblocNotas()   
        elif self.telegram:
            abrirtelegram()
        elif self.spotify:
            abrirSpotify()
        elif self.shutdown:
            apagarequipo()
    
    def Run(self):

        with sr.Microphone() as mic:
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            self.engine.say(' Jueves te escucha ')
            self.engine.runAndWait()
            self.audio = r.listen(mic, 5) 
        try:
            comando = r.recognize_google(self.audio, language = 'es-AR')
            print(comando)
            self.Interpretar(self.comando) # lo que se debe hacer con el comando de audio
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.engine.say(' Jueves no te puede entender ')
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            # si no se tiene conexión a internet o al servicio de google
            self.engine.say(' No pude obtener respuesta del servicio de Google Recognition ')
            print(" No pude obtener respuesta del servicio de Google Recognition ; {0} ". format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Jueves = Asistente()
    Jueves.Run()
```

Los resultados de la consola son estos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error ya te dice lo que está pasando. Tu objeto Asistente no tiene el atributo comando. No hay mucho más que decir. No querrías haber pasado "comando" SIN "self."? Comando como variable local si existe. De hecho la creas en esta linea: `comando = r.recognize_google(self.audio, language = 'es-AR')`

Comment: Ahora me salta este error, como que le estoy poniendo un argumento mas de el que recibe:
  File "c:/Users/Jeremias Davison/Desktop/Assistant Jueves/contraseñaRandom.py", line 71, in Run     
    self.Interpretar(self.comando) # lo que se debe hacer con el comando de audio
TypeError: Interpretar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Y por que le quieres pasar el argumento comando? No lo usas en ninguna parte de la función interpretar.

Comment: Hay dos soluciones a ese otro problema. Cual eligas dependerá de cual sea tu intención a la hora de escribir el código. O no le pases el argumento comando, o pasaselo y haz que la función acepte un argumento extra.

Comment: self en la practica no cuenta como argumento. De todos modos, self.comando es un atributo de tu objeto, lo podes acceder dierectamente en interpretar. Si quisieras pasar un comando que no es atributo, ahi sí deberías agreagar un parametro más en Interpretar